# Traveling to Canada via Turkey

Tags: visas, turkey, visas-on-arrival, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens

Pakistani with Canadian PR. I am getting a flight option via turkey with a 21 hours layover. The airlines are different and I am not sure if there's code sharing.

I have a friend and I would like to use this 21 hour window to visit him.

1. Will i be getting a transit / on arrival visa by the airlines?  (seems unlikely since two different airlines)

If not,

2. Can I go for the e-visa option for Turkey?
3. How long before should i apply for evisa since i will be traveling end of December 2015?

Is it it a safe option since I don't want to be stuck in at airport for 21 hours?

Comment: also take a look at the official ministry of foreign affairs website http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

Answer (score 3):

There is no visa on arrival in Turkey.

You have to apply for it in advance at the [official website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr).

As you have permanent residency in a OECD member state, you are eligible to apply online, assuming you can provide:

1. Sufficient funds for the term of your stay ($50 per day)
2. On-going ticket.

The process is straight forward. Simply follow the steps online. The default visa validity is 180 days, and a stay cannot exceed 30 days.

In practical terms, what that means is - if you apply for the visa today (September 13):

1. Your visa is valid from 13th September to 10 March 2016; this means you have to travel within these days.
2. You should plan on arriving within 3 months of the date you apply for your visa.
3. Once you entry Turkey, you can stay a maximum of 30 days.

Comment: thanks.this 180 days visa is good to travel for how long? a month or 3 months? in other words,when should one apply for it?